# Is a Raspberry Pi 3 capable of running a wireless printer server, a VPN and an Owncloud server?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, network-printer, owncloud

I'm considering buying a device to do three things:

1. Connect a USB printer and print to it wirelessly (from tablet and laptop)
2. Run a VPN server
3. Run an Owncloud/Nextcloud server

Is a Raspberry Pi 3 capable of doing all of this or should I consider some other device?

Answer (score 3):

1. Sure, a Pi3 would be a pretty good print server.  It's a bit more complicated than you need though.  Spend USD $60 on a printer that already has WiFi built in and you've got one less thing to maintain.  But yes, it would work.
2. I would think that the Pi3 would handle at least a few VPN connections.  I wouldn't try to run a few hundred through.
3. Owncloud requires an Apache server with PHP and a relational database.  Now you're starting to push it.  You've got 1 gig of RAM on the card.  Owncloud recommends 512MB with an absolute minimum of 128MB.  Between the O/S, Owncloud, and a relational database you likely couldn't run a windowing system too.  And I wouldn't expect too wonderful of performance.